# requirejs not loading properly

Tags: express, requirejs

This is probably a beginner mistake. I get this error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"     require.js:1

I setup a basic express server then I load my index.html like that:

```
app.use('/' ,function(req,res,next) {
    res.sendfile("index.html", {'root':"../"});
});
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> blabvla </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> BLABLALBLAL </h1>  
        <section id="app">

        </section>

        <footer> </footer>
        <script  data-main="application/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Main.js (require config)

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        text: '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
    }
});

require([
    'backbone',
    'views/app',
    'routers/router'
], function (Backbone, AppView, Router) {
    /*jshint nonew:false*/
    // Initialize routing and start Backbone.history()
    new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
    console.log("TEST !!!");
    // Initialize the application view
    var appview = new AppView();
    appview.render();
});
```

Console.log(("TEST!!"); is not appearing when I load my page.

The error still appears when I comment whole main.js file !

Answer (score 0):

Extreme noob mistake, my express root directory wasn't well configured!